# Google books API - Is it mandatory to have an api key for a website?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, key

I am making a website and I need to use Google Books API, but I don't know if it is mandatory to have an API key. I know that I can make queries without API key but I don't know if I have to have one as part of a website. The queries will only be made by users when they type in a search bar, and I dont pick up any informations about the queries, they will only be displayed. Here's my very simple javascript code :

```
searchInput.addEventListener("input", () =>
{
    $.getJSON("https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=" + searchInput.value, function(data)
    {
        console.log(data)
    })
})
```

It's just the beginning.